# Training Error -- what's the point?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, training-data

What's the overall point of training error in the goal of regression (i.e, making predictions)?

You might say something like, "well, you see, training error can help you determine which model of complexity is the best to use. "

And to that, some would say, "No you can't. Low training error could just mean that your model is conforming to whatever data you're training the model with, A.K.A overfitting"

What's the point of calculating training error if it's not a good predictive measure of performance?

Especially when we go through and say, to hell with training error, just use validation error..

When will we ever use training error?

Low training error can be indicative of overfitting.. is that the only use of it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for this question. Take a look at [this Meta Stack Exchange Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524/273585) for some more appropriate suggestions.

Comment: that's a good suggestion

Answer (score 7):

Training error by itself can be a very bad metric of your model performance, as you have correctly pointed out. However, there is no going around the fact that you *need to train* your model to make some meaningful predictions.

That is why you need training, validation and the test phases and data sets. The overfitting that can easily happen in the training dataset can be alleviated to some extent by using the randomly sub-sampled validation dataset because if you have overfitted, your model will not generalize (you should see that your training error does down monotonically as the model complexity increases but your validation error plateaus at some point and additional model complexity actually increases the validation error). However, if you do not do any training of the model, you do not have a model to validate!

The model needs to be trained. There is no getting around that. However, training error by itself is useless. One needs to perform cross-validation in order to ensure that the model is *generalizable*. The bottom line is that *anything* you use which the model has seen to during the training phase to evaluate it's performance is invalid. It is useful for model fitting but not for evaluation.
The correct way to do so is cross-validation regardless of what the OP claims in the discussion below.

You should look into the concept of **bias-variance tradeoff** as this has a direct bearing on your question and should clarify your doubt.

Comment: So basically you're saying that training error is useless except to help spot overfitting. Is that correct?

Comment: By itself, it has little value, yes. It **cannot** spot overfitting. That bit is done by the validation dataset. The training phase can overfit especially for complex models and that is when cross validation is very critical. You are over thinking it...training error is just the error between the true labels and the predicted labels during the training phase. It is just the residue left over after the optimization. There is nothing special about the training error per se. It is just that you need to cross-validate after the training phase to ensure that your model is generalizable.

Comment: No no no.. low training error can HELP spot overfitting. 'help' was a little word you missed there ;). Why does it help? It helps because if you have low training error but high test error, you're overfitting. The point of the validation set is so that you can choose the correct tuning parameters.. such as lamda star in ridge regression. I have to split this up into several comments...

Comment: You can spot overfitting in other ways, such as coefficients that are really large in magnitude which ridge regression helps take care of.

Comment: And actually, training error is usually defined as the *average* of rss, or whatever loss function you would like to use. Rss being sum((actual -prediction)^2) maybe I'm being too technical with the details..

Comment: This is only valid for particular models and can be a good rule of thumb but depending on the regularization you use, you can still end up with an over fitted model without having some coefficients blowing up. Regularization can control certain forms of overfitting but you cannot guarantee it (you cannot guarantee it even after cross validation but anyhoo...)

This is, unfortunately, more of an art than science ;-)

Comment: You should look into the bias-variance tradeoff as this has a direct bearing on your question.

Comment: I agree, you can define training error without taking the average. And I agree that you can have overfitting without large coefficients-- it's just one of the signs of a model that's overfit. As for the bias-variance tradeoff, it really doesn't have anything to do with whether or not training error has any use other than helping to spot overfitting. Why am I saying that? First of all high variance already covers overfitting, which was already addressed. I have to split this into two comments..

Comment: Secondly, validation error is what is used to determine the best bias-variance ratio.. which is why you end up with methods like ridge regression and lasso regression.. it's all about figuring out how to balance bias and variance using a good tuning parameter, which you choose with validation error - not training error. That's why I say it has nothing to do with training error, and hence nothing to do with my question (at least directly)

Comment: Training error will *not* help you spot overfitting. I am not sure why you say that. Hence, the idea of CV. Bias and variance is intimately related to model selection, which is what your confusion is about if you think more about it. There is *nothing* special about training error. It is just that you can adjust model complexity to minimize this to arbitrary precision and hence you need an independent dataset to judge your model on something your model has not previously seen (which is your validation set).

Comment: dude you couldn't be more wrong about training error *not* helping to spot overfitting. consider looking up the  definition of overfitting. I'll help you out: https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-regression/lecture/u8c2x/defining-overfitting

Comment: The fact that training error is used in the definition of overfitting there is why you couldn't be more wrong about , "Training error will not help you spot overfitting"

Comment: The training error is used to guide the optimization process to a minima and not to diagnose overfitting. It is the cost function of your model fitting process. The training process *produces* overfitting...not diagnose it... Anyway....all the best.

Comment: if you define training error the same way you are defining your loss function, i.e, you define training error as rss and you define your loss function used in your hill climbing algorithm as rss, then yes: Training Error is used to guide the optimization process. .

Comment: However, If you define training error as the *average* of your loss function, and use just use the loss function in your hill climbing / gradient decent algorithm, then no, training error does not guide the optimizations process to a minima..

Comment: Either way, the definition of overfitting uses training error in the definition, and hence, "not to diagnose overfitting" is not accurate. "Cannot diagnose overfitting without looking at test error as well as training error" is accurate. I feel like we're on the same page but I'm being more precise with wording, and your imprecision is why there is a disagreement in the first place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120444/discussion-between-pankaj-daga-and-jill-russek).

Comment: I think what's missing is that you aren't aware that training error and the loss function that is used in your gradient decent algorithm (hill climbing) do not have to be defined as the same thing. For instance, it's common to use a loss function (such as RSS) in your gradient decent algorithm (optimization) and then define the training error to be RMSE which is the square root of the *average* of the loss function (so sqr(rss/n)).. So technically, no, it's not exactly what is minimized in the optimization process.

Comment: Because you defined training error as the "average" in your last comment but said early it doesn't have to be that way, and because you're still arguing about training error not being a way to diagnose overfitting, when I just clarified that.. I think you're just trolling at this point ;)

Comment: Well, good luck to you. I am done with this conversation. Do not have all day.

Comment: Is it true that for a neural network with 2+ hidden layers and only linear activations f(x)=x, adding more layers will unlikely improve the training error ??